# Google maps and directions not showing using javascript api

Tags: javascript, html, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I am using google maps api to show a map and directions. The user click button to get location and the geo-location is not asking for permission and the map or the directions panel don't show up, any help?...

javascript

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false"></script>
<script>
var x = document.getElementById("demo");
function getLocation() {
    if (navigator.geolocation) {
        navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(showPosition);
    } else {
        x.innerHTML = "Geolocation is not supported by this browser.";
    }
}
function showPosition(position) {
    var lat = position.coords.latitude;
    var lon = position.coords.longitude;
    var directionsService = new google.maps.DirectionsService();
    var rendererOptions = {draggable: true};
    var directionsDisplay = new google.maps.DirectionsRenderer(rendererOptions);
    var destin = new google.maps.LatLng(43.52,-89.91);
    var mapOptions = 
    {
        zoom: 13,
        mapTypeId:google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
        center:destin,
        travelMode:google.maps.TravelMode.DRIVING,
        mapTypeControl:true
    };
    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("mapdisplay"),mapOptions);
    directionsDisplay.setMap(map);
    directionsDisplay.setPanel(document.getElementById("directionsPanel"));

    function calcRoute() {
        var start = new google.maps.LatLng(lat,lon);
        var end = new google.maps.LatLng(43.52, -89.91);
        var request = 
        {
        orgin:start,
        destination:end,
        travelMode:google.maps.TravelMode.DRIVING,
        };
        directionsService.route(request,function(response,status) {
            if(status==google.maps.DirectionsStatus.OK) {
                directionsDisplay.setDirections(response);
            }
        };
    }
}

function showError(error) {
    switch(error.code) {
        case error.PERMISSION_DENIED:
            x.innerHTML = "User denied the request for Geolocation."
            break;
        case error.POSITION_UNAVAILABLE:
            x.innerHTML = "Location information is unavailable."
            break;
        case error.TIMEOUT:
            x.innerHTML = "The request to get user location timed out."
            break;
        case error.UNKNOWN_ERROR:
            x.innerHTML = "An unknown error occurred."
            break;
    }
}
</script>
```

html

```
<body>
<p id="demo">Click the button to get your position:</p>
<button onClick="getLocation()">Try it</button>
<br><br>
<div id="mapdisplay" style="float:left;width:600px;height:400px;"></div><br>
<div id="directionsPanel" style="width:600px;height:400px;"></div>
</body>
```

Comment: Voting to close because it is unclear what you're asking. Please edit your question to clarify what you're trying to accomplish/what isn't working.

Comment: there is a syntax-error in your script(the parens for the call of `directionsService.route` are not closed)

Answer (score 2):

Do you know that there is a dev console on every good browser ? You are missing a parenthesis line 51 :

```
directionsService.route(request,function(response,status) {
    if(status==google.maps.DirectionsStatus.OK) {
        directionsDisplay.setDirections(response);
    }
});
```

You are not going anywhere if you don't use the console, so make sure you know the dev tools of your browser(s).

Comment: I fixed that and no console errors, the map shows but the not directions panel, any ideas?